# Xamarin iOs: How to customize background color of top bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How to customize background color of top bar?
as you can see it is appearing white
and the navigation drawer color I have set to white
so its not visible

[image: ckground]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this in xamarin.forms

```
var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
```